# what is different between res.setHeader and res.header in this code( see below)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, security

1. 

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', process.env.CLIENT_URL);
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE'
  );
  res.setHeader(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization'
  );
  next();
});
```

and 2.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, ContentType, Accept");
  next(createError(404));
});
```

what is different between 1. and 2. ? what should I use it

or should I declare use(cors()) for preventing COR access error like this

```
app.use(cors());
```

is this enough for me?

Comment: Basic function of both is to set the headers,you can use any that your comfortable with

Comment: I already set 2. but should I have to set app.use(cors()); too ??

Answer (score 1):

Both of those functions set the headers.

use `res.setHeader()` when you have only 1 header to set.
use `res.header()` if you have a bunch of headers to set.
Basically `res.header` is alias of `res.set`

Hope this short answer gives you the differences of both of them.

using cors() for app.use() makes your server to accept any kind of request which may not be acceptable ( avoid in production deployments to ensure security ) but still it's up to the server, developer and application to use cors() or not.